# Windows-based Network With Ubuntu Server?

Tags: server, windows-7

I'd like to add an Ubuntu Server to a network including several Windows7 machines.

What must I do in order to allow the `Ubuntu Server` to be 'allowed' to access the **home directory** on each one of the windows7 machines, and copy them over (for backup purposes)?

Also, once I install `MySQL` on the `Ubuntu Server`, how do I 'allow' all the Windows7 machines to connect to it (I'd like them to be able to query/update the databases etc)?

Please and thank you.

Comment: Hi user58925, thank you for your questions.  Since this is actually two separate questions, you should consider separating the two so that they can be answered separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the first question, what you are asking is kind of the reverse of what is normally done.  Normally, you would setup the Ubuntu server with [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) to serve the user's files. Samba can even be used as a NT4 style domain to centrally handle authentication, auditing, and authorization unless you are using Windows 7 Home Edition. [The Ubuntu Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/windows-networking.html) is a great place to start when setting up a samba server. You could set up Samba shares for each of your users and then they can save the files at their discretion.

If you are simply interested in a backup server, [Bacula](http://www.bacula.org/en/) may be more what you are looking for. You could set up a **Bacula Director** on your Ubuntu server, and then configure **Backula File** on each of your clients.  Once again, the [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/bacula.html) can help you set this up.

You could share the home directories of all of the users on all of your windows machines and setup mount points on the Ubuntu Server and setup a cron job to back the files up to the server.  This will quickly get cumbersome as you add and subtract machines.  Let me know if this is really what you want to do and I will try to get you some instructions.

As for your second question, it depends entirely how you want to access your database.  If you want to access the server directly, you will need edit the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file and edit the `bind-address = 192.168.0.2` parameter and change `192.168.0.2` to the ipv4 address of the server to listen over the network. Once again, this is documented in the [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/mysql.html).

You could also use [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) to access the database from any browser.  Once again, [The Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/phpmyadmin.html) has instructions to set this up as well.

Good Luck.